# File didn't update

Tags: file, codeigniter, ubuntu, bind

I just try to edit a file named named.conf.local which located on server (BIND).
When I run the webpage it showed File written!, but when I check the file (named.conf.local) there is no update.

Here are my controller:

```
function index() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'file'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('domain_name','Domain Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'Mail', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('localhost', 'Localhost', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('dns_form');
    } else {
        $domain_name = $this->input->post('domain_name');
        $mail = $this->input->post('mail');
        $localhost = $this->input->post('localhost');
        $data = $domain_name . "\n" . $mail . "\n" . $localhost;

        if (!write_file('/etc/bind/named.conf.local' . $domain_name, $data, 'a+')) {
            echo 'Unable to write this file';
        } else {
            echo 'File written!';
        }
    }
```

I have give permission for the location `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/bind/named.conf.local`. What's wrong with my program?

Thank you for helping me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the path to your file is correct? Does it work when you remove the $domain_name variable from this line, like below?

```
if (!write_file('/etc/bind/named.conf.local', $data, 'a+')) {
```

Comment: yaps, that was my fault. I've changed it, and now it works. Thank you